# IF ELSE in PHP is not executing, debugged and still cannot find issue

Tags: php, html, postgresql, post

I've used php before and never run into this problem....

I have radio buttons which pass on their own value. When my form is submitted I have verified that the value passed matches the if statement condition in my code. However, it will not execute that path.

For example, when the city radio button is selected, the if condition pertaining to city does not execute. I have debugged by placing an echo statement ahead of the if statement and it matches the value in the if statement, hence my confusion on why it does not execute.

If anyone can help I'd be grateful... I'm quite baffled.

Heres the html:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Lab 5</title>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='SearchForm.css' type='text/css' media='all' />
</head>
<body>
<p>You may use % as a wildcard character in your search.</p>
<form method='POST' action='index.php?type=search'>
  <input type='text' name='search_param' value='' />
  <input type='radio' name='search-type' value='City' id='city' />
  <label for='city'>City</label>
  <input type='radio' name='search-type' value='Country' id='country' />
  <label for='country'>Country</label>
  <input type='radio' name='search-type' value='Language' id='language' />
  <label for='language'>Language</label>
  <br /><br />
  <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Search' />
</form>
<p>Or, <a href='index.php?type=insert'>perform an insertion.</a></p>
</body>
</html>
```

and the php:

```
<?php

include 'connect.php';

$table = $_POST['search-type'];
$search = $_POST['search_param'];

if($table != NULL)
{
        echo '<table>';

        if($table == 'City')
        {

                $query = "SELECT * FROM city WHERE name ILIKE $1 ORDER BY name;";
                $stmt = pg_prepare($connection, "city", $query);
                $result = pg_execute($connection, "city", array($search));

                while($row = pg_fetch_assoc($result))
                {
                        cityTable($row);
                }
        echo '</table>';

        }

}
else
{
        echo 'Please select a table to query!';
}
```

As you can see, I've even removed the variable `$search` from my if condition, instead going straight to the post.

When I've echoed `$search` it yields "city" so..... please help!

Comment: try to change name='search-type' with name='search-type[]'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

String comparisons in PHP are case sensitive, so instead of:

```
if($_POST['search_param'] == 'City')
```

You should have:

```
if (0 === strcasecmp($_POST['search_param'], 'City'))
```

Or:

```
if (0 === strcasecmp(trim($_POST['search_param']), 'City'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the conditions:

```
$table = isset($_POST['search-type']) ? $_POST['search-type'] : false;
$search = isset($_POST['search_param']) ? $_POST['search_param'] : false;

if ($table) {

}
else if (!$table || $table === null) {

}
```

The HTML form might be posting the parameter search-type but as a blank (which is not null).

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Try this:

```
$table = isset($_POST['search-type']) ? $_POST['search-type'] : NULL; // string from radio
$search = isset($_POST['search_param']) ? $_POST['search_param'] : NULL; // string from input
```

Comment: Yes that is correct, part of my debuggin process, code updated. but it still doesn't work. I've even echoed $table one line above the condition and it yields 'City', yet it won't work!

Answer (score 0):

I think you want

```
        if($table == 'City')
```

$_POST['search_param']   is the value in the text box.

Comment: You are correct, that was left over from part of my debugging, yet it still won't work! other suggestions!?

Answer (score 0):

```
if($table != NULL)
{
        echo $table;

        if($search != NULL )
        {
```

the search param is the value which we get at the input text field my friend

Answer (score 0):

No one has noticed undefined $1 in the query :D

Comment: That's how you set up a bound parameter using pg_prepare: http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-prepare.php